# Ms Teams cant call member that actually existed

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm sorry, here I've no clue about what happen. So, there is no workaround or something that I'v try.

My ms teaams in my company seems have problem when working hours. Such as:

1. Missing folder in sharepoint or onedrive
2. Cant call member that already listed.
3. Calenders ocasionally blank.

PS : No probs in internet connection.

I'm just regular member of Ms Teams, buat really confussing. Theres no clear confirmation from IT depart.

Can anybody help to explain what happen? As I know Ms Teams using cloud. Or Ms Teams using personal "server" may be? So when it's busy some problem happen.

Thanks very much for any responses.

[sample if I call out of work hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r6ty.jpg)

[can't call name nadhira.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btiPd.jpg)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please elaborate more on issue.
>> Are you not able to see any folder/file in your teams SharePoint?
>> Do you mean you can't call anyone on your list?
>> Calendar is always blank?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Calendar was blank when work hour. I can see folders and files too, but when work hour, occasionally show "file not exist". Then, I mean "call" is try to add member (channel) or invite. Issue is same, when work hour some name can't show up. (attached image above, comparasion when I type nadhira on work hour & free hour)

Comment: Could you please post this to [Product support channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels)